# A-Frame with aframe-physics-system - address cannon elements from javsascript?

Tags: three.js, physics, aframe

I'm in an A-Frame scene, using its underlying three.js to create objects like:

> ```
> var boxMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: boxTexture, side: THREE.BackSide, bumpMap: boxBumpMap } );
> var boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 20, 20, 20 );
> var box01 = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, boxMaterial);
> scene.add(box01);
> ```

How can I, using javascript, address the underlying Cannon.js of aframe-physics-system to add the StaticBody attribute?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here... could you give more detail on what you're trying to do, and how you've tried to do it? Also see https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system/#using-the-cannonjs-api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm quite sure you cannot add DOM attributes to js non-DOM objects, such as `THREE` objects.

The static body attribute is actually creating a new object (`CANNON.Body` with its `type` set to `Cannon.Body.STATIC`). What `aframe-physics` does is synchronization - the **THREE.js mesh** with the  **Cannon.Body**.

Source code: body creation [here](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system/blob/master/src/components/body/body.js#L45-#L53), and syncing [here](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system/blob/master/src/components/body/body.js#L314-#L338).

You could create a **CANNON.Body** and synchronize its position with your box, but i would approach it differently:

You can have an empty `a-frame` entity with the physics attribute:

```
<a-entity position="0 2 -3" three-setup dynamic-body></a-entity>
```

but with the material and geometry set in a `a-frame` component:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("three-setup", {
  init: function() {
     var boxMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
         side: THREE.FrontSide,
     });
     var boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(1, 1, 1);
     var box01 = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, boxMaterial);
     this.el.setObject3D('mesh', box01)
  }
})
```

Check it out in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/se6z2ypd/)

As Don McCurdy pointed out, having a custom `a-frame` component has more advantages:
- You can listen for the `body-loaded` event which will notice you when the `CANNON.Body` is initialized
- it will be accessible with a simple reference: `this.el.body`

---

Otherwise, you would need to create a `CANNON.Body`, and on each render loop apply its position and rotation to your box.

Comment: @marqso if you want any elaboration feel free to ask

Comment: This looks about right! Couple small notes though – best to use `el.setObject3D('mesh', box01)` so that the mesh will be accessible in the way most components expect. And once you've done that, adding `el.setAttribute('static-body', 'shape: box');` should start physics initialization. Physics will emit a `body-loaded` event when it's initialized, after which `el.body` contains the CANNON.Body object. See: https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system/#dynamic-body-and-static-body

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Thanks for the notes, I've added them to my anwser !

Comment: Thanks, @DonMcCurdy! Yeah, that's what I was looking for.